# Best practice to reset angular 7 form

Tags: angular, html

I am using Angular 7. In my project I've used `Template Driven form`. I'm resetting form using `<input type="reset">` and it works fine. But I'm confused on which is better- `<input type="reset"` or form `reset()`?

Comment: Also use `resetForm()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better way is to use `reset()` of form as it resets the states of the form controls so any validation styling and errors reset also to the original pristine condition.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest and cleanest way to clear forms and their error states you can use reset().

```
this.myForm.reset();
```

You can refer [angular forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms)

I hope this will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Functionaliy is going to be same.

Since you are using Template Driven form you can go with `<input type="reset">`

For Reactive forms you could use `reset()`

`reset()` is preferred when you have unit test in place.